# Two CMOS switches connected in series

Tags: cmos

I have seen some circuits like the one below; why do they use two switches in series instead of one switch? Aren't two switches in series equivalent to doubling the length of one?

[image]

I'm sorry that I didn't describe my problem clearly. It may be clearer to see my newly uploaded picture. In fact, this is a cds circuit. When the switch is closed, a unit gain amplifier is formed, and when the switch is open, it works as a comparator to obtain the comparison result of the input change value. I have some doubts about how to design these two switches. This circuit does not require much speed and pays more attention to accuracy, so I think that the size of the switch should be the smallest w and l. But my instructor suggested to me to choose two The switches are connected in series, which makes me puzzled.

[image]

Comment: Since they have different in-signals (V1, V2...), how could they easily be replaced by a single switch? They are effectively AND gates.

Comment: Please try elaborating the question

Comment: <<< Aren't two switches in series equivalent to doubling the length of one? >>> One switch is generally ok. Two serial switches (as used in audio, but serial/parallel) are used for minimizing "pass-through" signals via capacitive parasitics link.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't describe it clearly, I added the question again, thank you

Comment: It appears that for some reason, you need to ass two switches in series in order to increase switch resistance in order to avoid feed through of input signal to output. This is because even in off state, the switch may conduct due to sub threshold conduction, thus contaminating the comparator output

Comment: ＠Sparsh   I have also had this conjecture, and I think that if the switch is turned off, due to the clock feedthrough effect, the midpoint of the two switches will be pulled high (if it is pmos), which may be able to achieve input and output isolation? But for the charge injection effect, increasing L should be more serious, maybe this is a compromise? I don’t know if I’m thinking about it correctly.